# Como se traduce al español "setting up to fail"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Estoy traduciendo sobre el acoso en el lugar de trabajo. Un ejemplo de conducta abusiva es

> setting up the person to fail

No queda bien

> preparar a una persona a que falle

Porque no es preparar es como sabotaje. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Podrías decir: "inducir al fracaso", o "tenderle una trampa para que se equivoque". Considerando cómo escribiste tu pregunta, te sugiero que, a la hora de traducir, tengas cuidado con la ortografía y la puntuación.

Comment: You need to post the entire sentence.

Comment: Merriam Webster: 13a: to put in a compromising or dangerous position usually by trickery or deceit No es trampa.inducir al fracaso, está muy bien como traducción.

Comment: @Lambie ¿No es trampa? No piensa lo mismo el Cambridge Dictionary EN-ES: "trickery: the use of tricks to deceive or cheat people - engaños, trampas" Ni el DLE, "trampa: 8. f. Ardid para burlar o perjudicar a alguien." La definición de uno es casi la traducción literal del otro.

Comment: No, trampa is ***a set up***; pero el **verbo**: to set someone up to do something no es **una trampa**.

Comment: @Lambie No, la expresión sugerida es "tender una trampa para que falle/se equivoque/fracase" Nadie ha dicho que el verbo sea "trampa". Tú mismamente has incluido una definición de set up que indica trickery/trampa.

Comment: No, estoy diciendo que to set someone up no es tender una trampa: to set a trap. There is no verbo trampa in Spanish and I never **said there was**.

Comment: @Lambie " el verbo: to set someone up to do something no es una trampa" Ni idea de lo que significa esa frase. Tomando como referencia la definición que has puesto, he añadido los términos que aparecen en el Cambridge y en el DLE, que demuestran que SÍ existe una relación con el término "trampa". Quizás debemos confiar más en tu palabra que en los diccionarios.

Comment: @RubioRic  Lo digo otra vez: "el **verbo** en inglés "to set someone up to do something" no es, en si, una trampa" .

Answer (score 4):

> An example of abusive behavior in the workplace is `setting up someone to fail`

Puede ponerse como:

> Un ejemplo de conducta abusiva en el lugar de trabajo es `tender una trampa` o `provocar el error` de alguien para que fracase.

Informalmente se dice también "boicotear", y existe una expresión muy usada con ese sentido perjudicial que es`hacer(le) una cama` a alguien ([el DLE la recoge](https://dle.rae.es/cama?m=form) a propósito de armar un engaño y preparar su caída en algún asunto)

Comment: La expresión "hacerle la cama a alguien" también es muy usada en España. Está recogida en el DLE: 1. loc. verb. Trabajar en secreto para perjudicarlo. https://dle.rae.es/cama

Comment: ¡Bien, gracias!  Puedo corregir  y consignar eso en la respuesta

Comment: Ojo, que en España es "hacerLE LA cama a alguien", en forma pronominal y con artículo determinado. Por otro lado, aunque la expresión es buena, quizás es demasiado informal  en relación a lo que se quiere traducir en este caso.

Comment: You have an English mistake: it's set **up** someone to fail. And it is not the idea of trampa, at all.

Answer (score 1):

"Inducir al fracaso"/"Inducir a una persona al fracaso" me suena bien, como lo comento Gustavson.

Answer (score 0):

"Mal prepararle(s) ____" (a la meta, al logro, ...) podría bastar.